# Android download file to internal app space

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download a file to my apps internal storage as I don't want the file to be accessible from outside my app.

Took a quick look at Androids DownloadManager.  Seems that I cannot use it to download a file to internal storage.  I noticed that the request I pass to the download manager is a Uri, so i had high hopes I could create a ContentProvider and pass a content Uri, yup no luck...

Am I missing something?

Does android provide another (possibly newer) framework to solve this problem?  I took a long look at WorkManager, but it doesn't have file specific download operations like pause/resume etc.

**EDIT:**

I did find a ticket on this.  Bummer, looks like no movement in Oreo.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37118684

Comment: You can use HttpUrlConnection to download any file to any storage location. 20 lines and you are done.

Comment: @greenapps, sure easy if in foreground, don't pause, don't lose network connectivity, etc.  DownloadManager is meant to handle all of that.  With the exception of being able to store internally.